# AndroidX migration error Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Resource ID #0x7f0b0047'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am having `MvvmCross` Xamarin Forms project. I right click on Android project and migarted to AndroidX. Now while I run I get error. Please help

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Resource ID #0x7f0b0047'

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = false, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity Instanace;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            Instanace = this;
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);

            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            // Name of the MainActivity theme you had there before.
            // Or you can use global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight
            //base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

            base.OnCreate(bundle); *------------------Here I get error*
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
        }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue even though my project doesn't use MVVMCross. It appeared when I updated the target SDK from 28 to 29 and few AndroidX packages were installed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this error in my app. It was failing in `FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ActivationFlags flags)`, when `ToolbarResource` was not set. This caused the following code to run: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/FormsAppCompatActivity.cs#L235

It turns out, that inflating `Resource.Layout.Toolbar` is problematic and causes the error you described.

The workaround is to assign the `ToolbarResource` (specifying a resource from your `Resource.Layout` in your `MainActivity` **before** `base.OnCreate()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean/Rebuild solution, sometimes the Resource.Designer.cs is not regenerated for some reason.

Comment: Thanks..I have alredy done and even deleted bin/obj files. still no luck